# docker: java based application resource duplication

Tags: java, docker

In a traditional environment, one has an application server that run in a VM. So the JVM is shared. For such Java applications, moving to a docker environment means that multiple JVM (one per container) runs in a single VM. This will duplicate the resource requirement, especially RAM. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: This isn't a Docker-specific issue, it's a consequence of having a distributed/microservice architecture.  Note that *typically* (but my no means always), the overhead of extra JVMs is small compared to the "real" memory usage of the service(s).

Comment: You seem to just be asking a simple yes or no question. Is there some elaboration you are looking for?